# AWS Lambda triggered by CloudWatch Events running too frequently

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am running code that makes an assumption about the last time it ran (checking a data source for updates in the last 300 seconds).

I set up the code to run on AWS lambda. I used the `rate(5 minutes)` initially but found it ran lambda every minute. I switched to `cron(0/5 * * * ? *)` and it ran every five minutes as expected, then suddenly started to run every 1-2 minutes.

Is there a setting I'm missing to ensure that the code is executed once and only once and that the trigger is truly every 5 minutes (give or take some seconds)?

Comment: Also check the lambda function at the AWS Console. Sometimes multiple cloudwatch triggers might be assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function fails or times out, it is retried asynchronously by Lambda. Cloudwatch events always triggers at the given rate. We have hundreds of cron triggered lambdas, and it always works as expected.